# How to make a function template a parameter to a test?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to unit test equivalent templated member function of a class template. (As a background, I want to offer the users of the library "classical" function notation with .bar() and a tacit notation with |, &, etc. But I do not want to duplicate the complete test code.)

```
#include <utility>   

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    template <typename U>
    auto bar(U&& u)&& {
        // whatever happens here. 
        return foo<T>();
    }

    template <typename U>
    auto operator|(U&& u)&& {
        return bar(std::forward<U>(u));
    }

    template <typename U>
    auto bar(U&& u) const& {
        // whatever happens here.
        return foo<T>();
    }

    template <typename U>
    auto operator|(U&& u) const& {
        return bar(std::forward<U>(u));
    }
};

int main() {
    using void_t = void();
    using op_t = foo<void>(foo<void>::*)(void_t)&&;

    op_t ops[] = {static_cast<op_t>(&foo<void>::bar<void_t>),
                  static_cast<op_t>(&foo<void>::operator|<void_t>)};

    for (const auto& op : ops) {
        auto sut = (foo<void>{}.*op)([](){});
        // test the behaviour of sut
    }
}
```

clang e.g., reports me that "the address of overloaded function 'bar' cannot be static_cast to type 'op_t'"

Or am I on the wrong track and this is not possible?
(I tried clang 6 and gcc 7)

Comment: What would `&foo<void>::bar<void_t>` be in the first place, given that `bar` is not a static member?

Comment: @HenningKoehler A pointer to member.

Comment: But for a non-static member to exist, you need to have an instance first ...

Comment: @HenningKoehler We don't need the member to exist, we only need a pointer.

Comment: I can get this code to compile by changing `op_t` to `using op_t = foo<void>(foo<void>::*)(void_t &&) &&;` and `sut` to `auto sut = (foo<void>{}.*op)(*[](){});`. Alternatively, instead of changing `sut`, you can also change `void_t` to `using void_t = void (*)();`.

Comment: @melpomene Many thanks. That solved my problem. (I would rate your questions as official solutions to my problem if you would state is a answer :-) )

Comment: Off Topic: starting from C++17, `std::void_t` is part of the standard (with a completely different meaning). To avoid clashes, I suggest to give another name to your `void_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the code to compile by changing `op_t` to

```
using op_t = foo<void>(foo<void>::*)(void_t &&) &&;
//                                          ^^
```

and `sut` to

```
auto sut = (foo<void>{}.*op)(*[](){});
//                           ^
```

(`[](){}` can be converted to a function pointer, but `*op` takes a reference to a function, so we have to dereference the pointer).

Alternatively, instead of changing `sut`, you can also change `void_t` to

```
using void_t = void (*)();
//                  ^^^
```

Now `void_t` is already a function pointer, so you don't have to dereference.